# Using Recursive CTEs in Power BI

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, common-table-expression, derived-table

Power BI has some limitations on Direct queries that has proved a hurdle for me to work around; when using direct Query Power BI takes any query that you input and adds a

```
Select * From(
```

statement to the beginning of the code, which prevents the running of any stored procedure, declaring variables, or use CTE Expressions to create temporary/derived tables.

I pulled the Stored Procedure Code out of the procedure, but i cannot figure out how to convert the whole statement from a CTE Expression to a derived expression. Does anyone know how to covert the query? i have only had success with the first select statement, but doing so prevents the Union, the Inner Join, and the relationship given between the two select Statements.

Original Procedure

```
WITH MaterialsTree(PartNo,SubPartNo,Descrip,Qty,Unit,Purchased,Vendor,TotalQty,UnitCost,UnitPrice,TotalCost,TotalPrice,TotalWt,
      StepNo,PartWt,Materials_ID,ItemNo, ParentID) AS 
(
    SELECT PartNo,SubPartNo,Descrip,Qty,Unit,Purchased,Vendor,TotalQty,UnitCost,UnitPrice,TotalCost,TotalPrice,TotalWt,
      StepNo,PartWt,Materials_ID,ItemNo, CAST(NULL AS INT) AS ParentID
        FROM Materials AS Mat
        WHERE PartNo = @PartNo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m.PartNo,m.SubPartNo,m.Descrip,m.Qty,m.Unit,m.Purchased,m.Vendor,m.TotalQty,m.UnitCost,m.UnitPrice,m.TotalCost,m.TotalPrice,m.TotalWt,
      m.StepNo,m.PartWt,m.Materials_ID,m.ItemNo, t.Materials_ID AS ParentID
        FROM Materials AS m
        INNER JOIN MaterialsTree AS t 
            ON m.PartNo = t.SubPartNo
)
SELECT PartNo,SubPartNo,Descrip,Qty,Unit,Purchased,Vendor,TotalQty,UnitCost,UnitPrice,TotalCost,TotalPrice,TotalWt,
      StepNo,PartWt,Materials_ID,ItemNo, ParentID 
FROM MaterialsTree
```

Comment: You can't convert a recursive CTE into a subquery, what you call a derive table. These are definitely *not* derived tables. In the simplest case there's no difference between subqueries and CTEs except the layout. When it comes to recursion though, a subquery can't refer to itself by name

Comment: As for calling that query in Power BI, you can create a view from that query and call the query from Power BI

Comment: I have created a View, but i need to be able to specify the Value in the first "where" callout; i will edit the question to show that as a parameter.

if it were a single item that needed the query a view would be great, but i cant parameterize the view to have it be adjustable

Comment: In that case you can create a function.

Comment: You can. `SELECT * from dbo.SomeFunction(123)`. I repeat, you can't perform a recursive query without recursive CTEs.

Comment: Besides, there's certainly a way to use stored procedures with Power BI

Comment: in Power BI you cannot use a stored procedure in Direct Query Mode; the 'official' answer, is to import the data into Power BI. however, that restricts you to only have data up-to-date during refreshed. otherwise you cannot put commands like "EXEC", "WITH" or others inside of a Select Statement.

Comment: Power BI's power comes from storing the data and analyzing it itself, not from mapping query results to charts

Answer (score 1):

I converted the Stored Procedure over to a Function; this was allowed. thank you for the guidance.